# Email reading and forwarding using php

Tags: php, email, sendmail

An email is located on server, could be accessed at a specific directory `/imap/domain/info/Maildir/cur/`.

How could I forward emails by reading and parsing raw email files?

As well is it possible parsing raw messages skip some parts of header, f.e. skip "Received: from mail by"?

Answer (score 0):

Open the file. Take the envelope address from the first `From` line. Drop the line. After that read the file line by line. Compare each line with a propper regular expression to drop unwanted received lines. Open a pipe to the mail inject program of your system (probably `sendmail`) and specify the envelope address of the recipient. Write the mail you have read to the pipe. Close the pipe.

Comment: As far as i tried the hard coded example, it used to fail sending such emails. I was using php `mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)`    
Maybe for beginning: how would it be possible to send a raw email message file located on imap directory without doing any changes.

Comment: Do what I have told you: open a pipe to sendmail: http://www.go4expert.com/articles/using-sendmail-php-t465/

Comment: Hi,  
so my hosting company does not support pipe from direct admin. Therefore i'm looking for php solution + cron.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure wether you **really** need to read the mail on the server or just parse incoming, the latter I do have expierence with, which is referred as "(E-)mail piping".

see e.g.

http://www.phpshare.org/articles/Piping-Incoming-Mail-with-PHP

If that doesn't answer you question or lead you in the right direction get back to me! :-)

Comment: Have no access deeper than php. As well the system uses Direct Admin for managing domains.

Comment: That doesn't matter, I would post some first random link to a Google result here, but the lesson should be to give it a shot first with your constraint and see where it leads. ( "(email/e-mail/mail piping direct admin" ) :-)